# What could be the reason for the white bar to the right on mobile screens?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I've been trying to clear the white bar to the right on mobile screens for my [website](https://riohs.com)  but nothing seems to work. See screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/p4mp2h) of the white bar when inspecting element, highlighted code does not include white bar [1](https://prnt.sc/p4mp2h)

[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/p4mq44) of the white bar when inspecting element, highlighted code includes white bar [2](https://prnt.sc/p4mq44)

FIRST, I thought some elements may be exceeding the width so i hid all sections but that didn't work.

SECONDLY, I disabled all the plugins thinking some plugin could be the cause but that didn't work either.

Wierd thing is that the bar only appears on the homepage while other pages are okay.

The closest clue i've come is suspecting `.text-page` to be the likely cause as its the only code that selects the padding to the right.

I have no idea how to fix it though i'm 80% sure its got to be CSS related.

I'd be very grateful for some help clearing the annoying bar.

Thank you

Comment: You should include your code in the question.

Comment: @dmnktoe I'm not really sure which code could be causing the problem unless i have to copy all the code for the website. Please advise.

Comment: The screenshot is broken. Can you re-upload them?

Comment: @Earid I re-uploaded the image and added it in footnotes but i guess because the link does not end with an image format its not being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white bar on the right seems to be caused by applying the css class `.row` to one of the div elements inside your `.container`

`.row` defines `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;`

What happens is that `.row` is being applied to a `div` element inside your container, but not to your header. So this `div` tries to push its boundaries for 15 pixels more than any other object. But, as the width limit is set by your device/browser, this div reaches the max-width and makes everything else in your page that doesn't have a negative margin shrink.

One of the solutions is to remove the `.row` class from this `div`. Another one would be to set an `overflow` property to your `.main-wrapper`, so the negative margin would still be contained within the wrapper, and wouldn't affect other elements of your page.

Please note that these solutions will result in different outputs, as the first one shrinks your content (and still has two white bars by its sides, which are caused by `.vc_column-inner`) and the second one prevents it from shrinking the rest of the website.

Comment: Thank @lzbernardo. I went with the overflow option and that worked great. I applied the css as follows:

`.text-page {`
`    overflow: hidden;`
`}`

and it fixed it great. I wasnt certain applying it to the '.row' class wont cause issues else where so i went with the `.text-page` class instead. Thanks a ton.